# New project wizard bugged on NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, plugins, netbeans-plugins

[image]

I have this for every categories, it's all blank except the one i select, the only thing i think may have caused problems is the fact that i've used this [plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/46257/praxis-live-look-and-feel) before. How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Changing back to "Metal"  *Preferred look and feel* seems to have fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

The [**Praxis LIVE look and feel - plugin detail**](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/46257/praxis-live-look-and-feel) itself states :

> ...
>   Because of the way this plugin is used in Praxis LIVE it overrides all
>   look and feel settings when installed - you'll need to uninstall it to
>   switch back to another look and feel. **Treat this as beta, or even
>   alpha! Some things might not show correctly yet, and certain icons
>   still need fixing**.

<sub>*(emphasis mine).*</sub>

As this is still in it's beta/alpha testing stage, I'd suggest you to uninstall this plugin, and switch back to the other look and feel.

Comment: @T4l0n -  In the Options window, go to the “Appearance” tab and then use the “Preferred look and feel” drop-down to select one of the built-in look and feels, which are “Metal”, “Nimbus”,etc. I'd suggest you to choose any of the default ones provided in NetBeans for fixing this issue. Also, from the next time please use(install) a stable version of any plugin, :)

Comment: @T4l0n - You should have upvoted and accepted my answer since I mentioned the same point in my comment. It's very bad habit to write your duplicate answer, when an answer which is correct has already been mentioned.